# How to remove black border on MediaElement WPF

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I have a MedialElement on my XAML, displaying an animated GIF.
All is working fine but I can't remove the black borders:

[image]

The size of the mediaelement is already the same size of the GIF and I've also wrapped it on Border tags, but still, the border is there:

```
<Border BorderBrush="white" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
   <MediaElement SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="<source>" Height="16"  
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,82" Name="medElemStatusWidget" 
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="16" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
</Border>
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's hard to see what borders do you want to remove. Can you show us a bigger pic?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mikk...The "black" colors on the corners is what I want to remove